# How to refresh page in angularjs after inserting record?

Tags: angularjs

After inserting a record in database using angularjs i want to reload/refresh the page. I read some solutions related to $route but i am unable to understand it. Can anyone tell me a simpler solution for that?

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$route.reload();
```

According to AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route):

Causes $route service to reload the current route even if `$location` hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, inject the `$window` dependancy, then:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to reload the page in angularjs to see record after inserting it.
- In Angularjs we Reload page only once in **STARTING** **And never** refresh page after that just Route to another location
- you need to route the page to another location by `ng-href="#/mydataentrylist"`
- To understand **when** , **how strong** to travel to another page in angularjs see [Angularjs Wire up a Backend example](https://angularjs.org/)

  Note : In Angularjs Wire up a Backend example they have never refreshed page just routed

> simpler solution

1. Do data entry on a form and click on **save button**
2. Click on button `ng-href="#/mydataentrylist"` that will take you to
   list of data entry form(Here it will **Route** and not **Reload/refresh**)
3. Please spend some time with [Angularjs Wire up a Backend example](https://angularjs.org/) to do in correct way